# equal size numerator and denominator

Tags: fractions

I am trying to size the numerator and denominator of the below equation so that they are equal in size.  I have not had much luck suggestions are appreciated.

```
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\frac{cf_{n}}{(1+i)^n}} {\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{cf_n}{(1+i)^n}} , n_{i}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Either remove `\displaystyle` or use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac` for the inner fractions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Probably you had added `\displaystyle` to get the superscript and subscript of the inner sum operator on top and below the symbol. This also increases the size of the fraction. Instead `\limits` can be used to move the superscript and subscript of the operator at the same place as in `\displaystyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  \sum_{i=1}^{n}
  \frac{\frac{cf_{n}}{(1+i)^n}}
       {\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{cf_n}{(1+i)^n}}
  , n_{i}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The following example makes the four math style visible:

① `\displaystyle`
    ② `\textstyle`
    ③ `\scriptstyle`
    ④ `\scriptscriptstyle`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\showms}{%
  \mathchoice
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\color{red}\ding{172}}}}%
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\color{red}\ding{173}}}}%
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\color{red}\ding{174}}}}%
    {{\scriptscriptstyle\text{\color{red}\ding{175}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \showms\sum_{\showms i=1}^{\showms n}
  \showms\frac{
    \showms\frac{\showms cf_{\showms n}}{\showms (1+i)^{\showms n}}
  }{
    \displaystyle
    \showms\sum_{\showms i=1}^{\showms n}
    \showms\frac{\showms cf_{\showms n}}{\showms(1+i)^{\showms n}}
  }\showms,
  n_{\showms i}
\]
\[
  \showms\sum_{\showms i=1}^{\showms n}
  \showms\frac{
    \showms\frac{\showms cf_{\showms n}}{\showms (1+i)^{\showms n}}
  }{
    \showms\sum\limits_{\showms i=1}^{\showms n}
    \showms\frac{\showms cf_{\showms n}}{\showms(1+i)^{\showms n}}
  }\showms,
  n_{\showms i}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with math styles]

**Legend:**

① `\displaystyle`
    ② `\textstyle`
    ③ `\scriptstyle`
    ④ `\scriptscriptstyle`

Comment: This is great!  I thought that all equations had to start with begin and end equation.  What is the underlying structure of the command?  This is very useful, thank you for your input

Comment: `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` is used for numbered equations. `\[`...`\]` or the environment form `\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}` are used for unnumbered equations. `$...$` or `\(...\)` are used for inline math.

Comment: How to print legend in document?..It ok..did it :)

Comment: @someoneelse With `amsmath` we also have `\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}` and `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively from [New command in TeX for fraction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/new-command-in-tex-for-fraction) and [Mathfixs package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/new-command-in-tex-for-fraction):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathfixs,amsmath,anyfontsize}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fr}[1]{%
  \fr@aux#1,,\@nil
}
\def\fr@aux#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \ensuremath{\frac{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \fr{\mbox{\fontsize{2mm}{2mm}\selectfont 5 - 2} ,\textstyle{\mbox{\fontsize{2mm}{2mm}\selectfont 6 - 1}}} = \fr{20,30} \]
\[\frac{\textstyle{\mbox{\fontsize{2mm}{2mm}\selectfont 5 - 2 }}}{\textstyle{\mbox{\fontsize{2mm}{2mm}\selectfont 6 - 1}} } = \frac{20}{30}\]
\end{document}
```

Notice the difference in vertical alignment between numerator and denominator when using each of the methods.

[image: Solution but with internal alignment difference]