# How to control the font size in complex fractions?

Tags: fractions

I am writing an equation and for part of that, I have the following fraction:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{u_{fe}\frac{\frac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}+    
\frac{u_{i+1,j,k}^n+u_{i+1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}-
u_{fw}\frac{\frac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}+
\frac{u_{i-1,j,k}^n+u_{i-1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}}
{dx_i + dx_{i+1}}
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

My problem is that the size of `u` in `u_{fe}` and `u_{i,j,k}` is different. I have also tried `equation`, `gather` and `split` but the problem is still there. 
`
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Change the `\frac` to a `\dfrac`

Comment: Related? [equal size numerator and denominator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133527/equal-size-numerator-and-denominator)

Comment: The question should be: *do you really want to inflict that on your readers?* Those 1/2 factors could go at the front.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a suggestion: *stop the madness*. All those fractions bars are confusing and make the expression diffcult to read. Don't inflict that on your readers. If you had complicated denominators, I would understand, but here it's preferable, in my opinion, to keep "one level of fraction", by putting most 1/2 factors in front of the expressions they multiply. See below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
    \frac{1}{dx_i + dx_{i+1}}
    \left(  
        \frac{u_{fe}}{2}
        \left(
            \frac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2} +
            \frac{u_{i+1,j,k}^n+u_{i+1,j,k}^{*}}{2}
        \right)
        +
    \right. \\
    \left.
        \frac{u_{fw}}{2}
        \left(
            \frac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2} +
            \frac{u_{i-1,j,k}^n+u_{i-1,j,k}^{*}}{2}
        \right)
    \right)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the `\frac` to `\dfrac`. See MWE below,

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{u_{fe}\dfrac{\dfrac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}+    
\dfrac{u_{i+1,j,k}^n+u_{i+1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}-
u_{fw}\dfrac{\dfrac{u_{i,j,k}^n+u_{i,j,k}^{*}}{2}+
\dfrac{u_{i-1,j,k}^n+u_{i-1,j,k}^{*}}{2}}{2}}
{dx_i + dx_{i+1}}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey just noted the link above. This question might be a possible duplicate. I might delete the answer in a few.