# New command in TeX for fraction

Tags: fractions

Now I need to redefine the fractions as follows

By writing `\fr{2,3}`, we get `$\frac{2}{3}$`. How can I achieve this? I have tried

```
\newcommand{\fr}[1,2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}
```

but got wrong.

Comment: `$\frac{2}{3}$` is more real and good IMHO :)

Comment: What if you wanted to write `\frac{1,000}{2,000}` ?

Comment: @EthanBolker `\fr{{1,000},{2,000}}`

Comment: I would also recommend against this, this would not be particularly readable for others.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following example defines `\fr` with one argument and separates the numerator and denominator via the help macro `\fr@aux`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fr}[1]{%
  \fr@aux#1,,\@nil
}
\def\fr@aux#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \ensuremath{\frac{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ \fr{2,3} = \fr{20,30} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A variant with error checking:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fr}[1]{%
  \fr@aux#1,,\@nil
}
\def\fr@aux#1,#2,#3\@nil{%
  \def\fr@param{#2#3}%
  \ifx\fr@param\@empty
    \errmessage{\string\fr: Missing comma}%
  \else
    \def\fr@param{#3}%
    \ifx\fr@param\fr@check
    \else
      \errmessage{\string\fr: Too many commas}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \ensuremath{\frac{#1}{#2}}%
}
\def\fr@check{,}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[ \fr{2,3} = \fr{20,30} \]

  % Trigger errors:
  \fr{1}
  \fr{2,3,4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need two commas in `\fr@aux#1,,\@nil`? I would naïvely think that `#1` corresponded to `#1,#2` in the defn. of `\fr@aux` and `,\@nil` corresponded to `,#3\@nil`. How should I be reading it?

Comment: @cfr The second comma is there in case the user forgets to put in the first comma.  Then if you wanted you could check for an empty argument and create a more meaningful error message than the one that would result without a second comma.

Answer (score 22):

It's quite easy with `xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fr}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\efrac#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\efrac}{mm}{\ensuremath{\frac{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
Here's \fr{2,3} and also in math $\fr{4,2}=2$.
\end{document}
```

The argument declared with `\SplitArgument` is expected to have one comma in it. The macro splits the argument into two braced components, that are passed as argument to `\efrac` which, in turn, has two arguments.

There's no convenience in being able to type `\fr{2,3}` instead of the clearer `$\frac{2}{3}$`, though. Trust me.

Comment: This must be one of the few times I see you using `\ensuremath` :-)

Comment: I suspect the OP has a keyboard where the curly braces are less easily accessible than is the comma. That, or saving three keystrokes relative to a regular `\frac` command...