# Prevent automatic resizing of equation elements

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, inline

I have the following equation:

```
\begin{equation}
E(W) = \frac{\frac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}}{(1-\rho)\sum_{n=0}^{c-1}(\frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!})+\frac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\rho} \cdot \frac{1}{c\mu}
\end{equation}
```

which is rendered as

[image]

Is there any easy way to prevent that the nominator and denominator of the main fraction to be each displayed in inline math mode? E.g. I want my summation to look like this [image] instead of the way it looks right now.

Comment: You can use \displaymath for example.

Comment: but as far as I understand this the equation is already in display math, or is there a way to force display math for the individual elements of the equation aswell?

Comment: add `\limits` directly after the `\sum` command `\sum\limits_{n=0}^{c-1} ...`

Comment: Sebastiano meant `\frac{\displaymath ...}{\displaymath ...}` so numerator and denominator are set in display style

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your help in English and for the explanation. :-)

Comment: Thanks all of you this has helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is my version using also `\displaystyle` and `\dfrac`. I not very good for the explanations :-).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
E(W) = \frac{\dfrac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}}{(1-\rho)\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{c-1}\left(\frac{(c\rho)^n}{n!}\right)+\frac{(c\rho)^c}{c!}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\rho} \cdot \frac{1}{c\mu}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However you can see also this link: [equal size numerator and denominator](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133527/equal-size-numerator-and-denominator)